# Unable to assert in test for QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults

Tags: unit-test, list, apex-email-service

I have a class for setting a default `ToAddress` when using a specific email action. See below:

```
global class EmailHandler implements QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler {
    // Empty constructor  
    global EmailHandler() {  
    }  
    // The main interface method  
    global void onInitDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {  
        System.debug(defaults);
        QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults sendEmailDefaults = null; 
        // Check if the quick action is the standard Case Feed send email action
        // and set sendEmailDefaults 
        for (Integer j = 0; j < defaults.size(); j++) {  
            sendEmailDefaults = (QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults)defaults.get(j);  
            System.debug('Email Defaults For Loop ' + j + ': ' + sendEmailDefaults);
            break;  
        }  

        if(sendEmailDefaults != null) {
            //select the relevant case
            Case c = [SELECT CaseNumber, Source__c, CC_Team__c, Subject, OwnerId 
                      FROM Case WHERE Id=:sendEmailDefaults.getContextId()]; 
            System.debug('Case ID: ' + c.Id);
            //select the user that owns the above case
            User u = [SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE Id=:c.OwnerId];

            EmailMessage emailMessage = (EmailMessage)sendEmailDefaults.getTargetSObject();

            //this will clear certain fields if using the centre console
            if (sendEmailDefaults.getActionName() == 'Case.CC_Send_Email') {
                emailMessage.ToAddress = '';
                emailMessage.CcAddress = '';
            }
            System.debug('To Address after clean: ' + emailMessage);       
        }
    }   
}
```

I am trying to write a test class for this which is shown below:

```
@isTest
private class EmailHandlerTest {
    static Case myCase {get;set;}
    static EmailMessage myMsg {get;set;}

    static testmethod void EmailPublisherLoader_NoReplyToId() {
        Exception failureDuringExecution = null;
        init();

        //create QuickActionDefaults
        List<Map<String, Object>> defaultSettingAsObject = new List<Map<String, Object>>
        {
            new Map<String, Object>
            {
                'targetSObject' => new EmailMessage(),
                    'contextId' => myCase.Id,
                    'ToAddress' => myMsg.ToAddress,
                    'CCAddress' => myMsg.CcAddress,
                    'actionType' => 'Email',
                    'actionName' => 'Case.CC_Send_Email',
                    'fromAddressList' => new List<String> { 'salesforce@test.com' }
            }
        };

            List<QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults> defaultsSettings = 
            (List<QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(defaultSettingAsObject), List<QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults>.class);

        Test.startTest();
        (new EmailPublisherLoader()).onInitDefaults(defaultsSettings);
        System.debug('defaultsSettings after: ' + defaultsSettings);
        Test.stopTest();
        //System.assertEquals(null, defaultsSettings.QuickActionDefaults.targetSObject.ToAddress);  
    }

    static void init(){
        myCase = 
            new Case(
                Status='Unassigned',
                Priority = 'Medium',
                Origin = 'Email',
                RecordTypeId = '012800000007qIgAAI'
            );
        insert myCase;

        myMsg = 
            new EmailMessage(
                ToAddress = 'ToAddress@test.com',
                CCAddress = 'CCAddress@test.com',
                ParentId = myCase.Id
            );
        insert myMsg;
    }
}
```

My problem is that while my test class seems to be working and my debug statement of `System.debug('defaultsSettings after: ' + defaultsSettings);` shows me that `ToAddress` has been blanked, I am not sure how to verify this using `System.assertEquals()` because I don't know how to access to value I need. Here is the output of that debug statement:

```
10:27:36:053 USER_DEBUG [35]|DEBUG|defaultsSettings after: (SendEmailQuickActionDefaults:[QuickActionDefaults.actionName=Case.CC_Send_Email, QuickActionDefaults.actionType=Email, QuickActionDefaults.contextId=50023000001yVHlAAM, QuickActionDefaults.targetSObject=EmailMessage:{ToAddress=}, emailTemplateId=null, fromAddressList=(), ignoreTemplateSubject=null, insertTemplateBody=null, replyToId=null])
```

My question is how do I access the `ToAddress` from the `defaultsSettings` list to check it is null for my test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by doing the following:

```
    //Do the tests
    Test.startTest();
    (new EmailHandler()).onInitDefaults(defaultsSettings);
    System.debug('defaultsSettings after: ' + defaultsSettings);
    Test.stopTest();

    //Assertions
    System.assertEquals('', defaultsSettings.get(0).getTargetSObject().get(EmailMessage.ToAddress));
    System.assertEquals('', defaultsSettings.get(0).getTargetSObject().get(EmailMessage.CcAddress));
```

I hadn't realised that `defaultsSettings` was actually a list rather than the settings themselves.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm not very familiar with the functionality of `QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler`*.

I was able to get your test class to pass with some additional assertions by doing this:

```
    Test.startTest();
    System.assertEquals(null, ((EmailMessage)defaultsSettings[0].getTargetSObject()).ToAddress);  
    (new EmailHandler()).onInitDefaults(defaultsSettings);
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertEquals('', ((EmailMessage)defaultsSettings[0].getTargetSObject()).ToAddress);
```

The `ToAddress` of your `EmailMessage` starts out as `null` (it's simply not populated in test context), and that's what your main class alters. Since the main class populates an empty string, we can detect the change.

Comment: Thanks David, I was able to get the test to work as well by doing something similar.